# Scope of java:global datasource definition

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I define a datasource definition with  in web.xml (or with @dataSourceDefinition) with a name java:global/jdbc/db. It works: I can use the datasource in the application. But, after the running of the application, I can't see a JDBC resource with this name (with or without java:global) in the administration console of GlassFish.

Neither I can't use the datasource to define a JDBC security realm with asadmin and use it afterwards in the application.

What is the scope of java:global? Isn't the definition available throughout the server? Or perhaps JDBC resource in GlassFish and datasource definition is not the same thing?